# WinForms MdiChildren Selection and Activation

Tags: c#, winforms, componentone

I am a fairly experienced WinForms developer. I have an MdiApplication that used to work well. However, recently the main shell of the application, for which we use ComponentOne RibbonForm, has been updated in a big way. This update did affect some of our other 3rd party components, which we established was due to ComponentOne's use of `DoEvents()` in their event code. I thought I had cleaned up all of the code causing problems but I now have found another...

When I have multiple `MdiChildren` open and select one of these in code from an button click event on the ribbon form via

```
document.Activate();
document.EditorControl.Select();
document.EditorControl.Focus();
```

the other open `MdiChildren` documents still have focus, that it the forms are highlighted and input is not set on the document I set in code. Two questions:

1. How can I ensure that the `Form` I want to make active is the *only* one that is active?
2. Linking to the above; setting one form as active using `form.Activate()` should deactivate the others `MdiChildren`, but it is not - how can I deactivate the other windows in code?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your first question confuses me...in what scenario is there _ever_ more than one active child?  The behavior of MDI is to do _exactly_ what you want so any other behavior seems contrived.

Comment: I can open more than one excel workbook, so I can have many mdi children active at any one time. The user can ley these out as they wish via a button (align horizontal, or what ever). I lay the items out and I want to restore the active window after the layout operation. Now, for some reason, when I do this, I get TWO active windows, the last one I moved programatically and the one I set after the operation. `form.Active()` should set `form` as the active one and by the default behavior, the others should deactivate, this is not happening. Why?

Comment: I am now having an issue with `C1Ribbon` and an MDI form that I suspect is due to their use of `DoEvents()`.  Could you expand on what you found that was causing you trouble?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I have provided an answer... Which was to long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

[Too long for a comment]

I am sick to the hind teeth with fighting C1. Esp. the Ribbon. I have confirmed with their support that they do use `DoEvents()` which they use to yield on their Gui threads. I am now going to switch to DevExpress which should be straight forward for my MVC application...

C1's use of `DoEvents()` messes up the normal flow of your application. `DoEvents()` is asynchronous which means it terminates before the application has actually processed any outstanding events, so if you're using it in a procedure with many sequential statements, calling `DoEvents()` causes a huge disturbance whenever it's called. This is what I think we are seeing when we perform our MDI operations, but we can never be sure without the C1 source code.

I hope this helps.